# Group by annotated value in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to get the number of elements by a category (mora_dias_categoria) that is a calculation of a model field but it doesn't group by correctly.

This is what I have tried:

```
metricasColombia = MetricasPrestamosColombia.objects \
            .annotate(mora_cantidad =Sum(F('total_habia_que_recibir')-F('total_recibido'))) \
            .annotate(mora_dias_categoria = Case(
                When(Q(mora_cantidad__gt=0) & Q(mora_dias__gt=0) & Q(mora_dias__lte=30),then=Value('mora_030')),
                When(Q(mora_cantidad__gt=0) & Q(mora_dias__gt=30) & Q(mora_dias__lte=60),then=Value('mora_3060')),
                When(Q(mora_cantidad__gt=0) & Q(mora_dias__gt=60) & Q(mora_dias__lte=90),then=Value('mora_6090')),
                When(Q(mora_cantidad__gt=0) & Q(mora_dias__gt=90),then=Value('mora_90')),
                default=Value('No mora'),
                output_field=CharField()
            )) \
            .values('semana','idPrestamo_id__idContactoInfo_id__ciudad__nombreCiudad','mora_dias_categoria') \
            .annotate(totalPrestamos=Count('idPrestamo_id'))
```

But still get this output (has duplicates when it should be aggregated):

```
[{'semana': '1-2020', 'idPrestamo_id__idContactoInfo_id__ciudad__nombreCiudad':
 'Medellín', 'mora_dias_categoria': 'mora_030',
 'totalPrestamos': 1}, {'semana': '1-2020', 'idPrestamo_id__idContactoInfo_id__ciudad__nombreCiudad': 
'Medellín', 'mora_dias_categoria': 'mora_030', 'totalPrestamos': 1}...
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just counting `id` instead of `idPrestamo_id`? Without seeing your models I can't really determine if this is the issue or not, but it's a thing to try.